# What happens with statistics when reverting to a database snapshot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, statistics

Lets say I have a database FOO for which I created a snapshot (named FOO_snap). Now I'll run thousands of queries on this DB. After that I will revert DB to FOO_snap. Will I lose all of the statistics which were created for these thousand of queries?

Comment: As stated in BOL: `any updates to the database since the snapshot's creation are lost`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179557(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Database snapshots are at the page level.  All changes to the source database will be stored in the snapshot and used to revert back to the original state. This includes pages that store user data, meta-data, and internal structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you would:

> *The original source database is overwritten by the reverted database, so any updates to the database since the snapshot's creation are lost.*

and

> *The metadata of a reverted database is the same as the metadata at the time of the snapshot.*

Quotes from [Revert a Database to a Database Snapshot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189281.aspx) in the MSDN Library.

Answer (score 2):

Further to Sporri's answer - you can check this if you are using SSMS.

> To view a database snapshot on a server:
>
> 1. In Object Explorer, connect to the instance of the Microsoft SQL Server  >Database Engine and then expand that instance.
> 2. Expand Databases.
> 3. Expand Database Snapshots, and select the snapshot you want to view.

When you do this, it gives you the list of objects that are included in the Snapshot, as it would with a normal database (right down to Statistics etc.)

Taken from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175469(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I'd love to know why I got a down vote for this - using this method gives you extra visibility of what you are getting from a snapshot - which added to the discussion and possibly/hopefully the OP's understanding.

Comment: Thanks up-voters. Would still like to know why the original person downvoted me, but I will make do with Justice!